# Native iOS - Good swift Storyboard/User Interface hacks

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am relatively new to native iOS and I want to build an Instagram-like newsfeed but I find it really tough to make it look that pretty.

Does anyone have any general swift hacks, tips or suggestions to make native iOS user interfaces really really pretty? Pretty much anything is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered. Your question is how to make user interfaces pretty - thats very abstract and depends on who you're asking. You should make your question more concrete, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This is a UICollectionView, but maybe you already knew that. Making the newsfeed isn't that hard I think, there just some pictures. The hard part is I think storing and retrieving data from a database

Comment: @Hapeki I tried to keep it broad on purpose to get some general tips, if any; but I stand corrected. Thank you :)

Comment: @J.Doe I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: No problem, you can always ask me if you contact me on my account :)